# Text Search in WPF ListView not working properly with selectionmode extended

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, text-search

I have a WPF ListView with selection mode set to Extended (and I need to keep it extended for other funationality). I have also enabled text search on this listview using TextSearch options.

Now consider I have following 5 items in ListView :

- Apple
- Ball ==> This is current selected item.
- Cat
- Dog
- Elephant

At this stage, if I press key "E" on keyboard, the text search works properly and the item "Elephant" gets selected. However, if I press "Shift + E", all items from Ball to Elephant gets selected, i.e. Shift key is used for extended selection and not for Capital Letter E. However, since I am doing a search using keyboard, shouldn't the only item "Elephant" get selected and shift key should be used for capital E and not for extended selection? Can we somehow achieve this?